# OpenCV 3.0 svm always predicts 0 (java)

Tags: java, opencv, classification, svm

I'm new to opencv's svm's. I tried a sample classifier but it only returns 0 as the predicted label. I even used the value 5 for training as well as the prediction.

I've been changing the values for about a hundred times but i just don't get what's wrong. I'm using OpenCV 3.0 with Java. Here's my code:

```
    Mat labels = new Mat(new Size(1,4),CvType.CV_32SC1);
    labels.put(0, 0, 1);
    labels.put(1, 0, 1);
    labels.put(2, 0, 1);
    labels.put(3, 0, 0);

    Mat data = new Mat(new Size(1,4),CvType.CV_32FC1);
    data.put(0, 0, 5);
    data.put(1, 0, 2);
    data.put(2, 0, 3);
    data.put(3, 0, 8);

    Mat testSamples = new Mat(new Size(1,1),CvType.CV_32FC1);
    testSamples.put(0,0,5);

    SVM svm = SVM.create();
    TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER,100,0.1);
    svm.setKernel(SVM.LINEAR);
    svm.setType(SVM.C_SVC);
    svm.setGamma(0.5);
    svm.setNu(0.5);
    svm.setC(1);
    svm.setTermCriteria(criteria);

    //data is N x 64 trained data Mat , labels is N x 1 label Mat with integer values;
    svm.train(data, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

    Mat results = new Mat();
    int predictedClass = (int) svm.predict(testSamples, results, 0);
```

Even if i change the lables to 1 and 2, I still get 0.0 as a response. So something has to be absolutely wrong... I just don't know what to do. Please help! :)

Comment: First of all i never worked with opencv svm package. I worked with libsvm with opencv in c++. So in libsvm you can not(i don't know about newest versions i used it nearly one and half year ago) test results only for one sample against the model. you have to put multiple sample images(can't remember how many images i put there, just put much as you can and check it by trail and eror) into test folder and check it with the model you created.And for the training how much samples you used? and there may be several reasons for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in C++. I'm not too sure if it's the same in Java but in C++ the predictions were saved in the results Matrix instead of returned as a float.

Comment: can you clarify further how you solve your problem i am having the same problem but couldn't find solution?

Comment: `Mat results = new Mat();
    int predictedClass = (int) svm.predict(testSamples, results, 0);` The results Mat will have the actual prediction whereas predictedClass will always be zero. @Yirga

Comment: @KevinBai Thanks toooooo much. It is totally what I was looking for. Unfortunately, OpenCV documentation does not give good explanation about such matters.